# How do you configure emacs for julia?

Tags: shell, debugging, auto-complete-mode

What is a recomended way for making emacs as julia code editor? The things which I would like to have are:

- autocomplete
- julia shell in emacs with abbility to send the code from buffer
- debugging

Comment: I do not know any julia-specific tool for Emacs, but as for the "send code from buffer to shell" part, I tend to use [`isend`](https://github.com/ffevotte/isend-mode.el), which is completely language-agnostic. *(disclaimer: I'm the author of `isend`)*

Comment: Have you tried a web search for "julia emacs"?  Have you tried the julia-mode that is distributed in the contrib directory of the Julia language?

Comment: I have tried to install ESS but it didn't compile under Ubuntu 15.04

Comment: Also I installed this one https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/contrib/julia-mode.el but I didn't get autocompletetion

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [ESS](http://ess.r-project.org/) development environment seems to [support julia out of the box](https://github.com/emacs-ess/ESS/wiki/Julia).

According to the documentation, it supports most of the features you mentioned:

- completion
- code evaluation
- error navigation (there doesn't seem to be a full debugger yet, though)

Comment: ESS does not compile for me

Comment: The error for `make` is: Cannot open load file: no such file or directory, julia-mode
Makefile:117: recipe for target 'ess-custom.elc' failed
make[1]: *** [ess-custom.elc] Error 255
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/akels/.emacs.d/ESS/lisp'
Makefile:10: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2

Comment: @JānisErdmanis Seems like until recently Julia mode wasn't packaged with the rest of ESS. If you got the distribution from, say, downloading a Tar file from ESS site, then it may not be there. Try pulling it from Github.

Comment: OK downloading latest release from https://github.com/emacs-ess/ESS/releases did solve autocompletition issues. However accesing the documentation for julia functions does not seem to work ;(

Comment: I had forgotten that I had installed julia development version v4.0. With version 3.11 ESS works out of the box :))

Comment: FYI, according to https://github.com/emacs-ess/ESS/issues/715, emacs/ess and julia *on windows* does not work, attributing the problem to something in Julia. The workarounds suggest using `*shell* julia` and/or not-ESS, using `run-julia` from the `julia-mode` package.

Answer (score 4):

I am currently using these 2 Emacs packages:

- [julia-mode](https://github.com/JuliaEditorSupport/julia-emacs)
- [julia-repl](https://github.com/tpapp/julia-repl)

everything is detailed in the [julia-repl author's blog post](https://tpapp.github.io/post/julia-workflow/).

It is the best I have found so far. I am quite happy with it and I prefer it to the previously cited ESS-Julia solution.

I still miss an auto-complete solution for Julia, though.

Answer (score 1):

The latest project in this field (as of 2020) is [Julia snail](https://github.com/gcv/julia-snail), which aims at providing development environment and REPL interaction package for Julia in the spirit of Common Lisp’s SLIME and Clojure’s CIDER.

It currently supports:

- REPL display and interaction
- cross-referencing
- auto-completion